# Change font settings in leadsheets package for chords (\chord{}, \writechord{})

Tags: leadsheets

For a couple of days I've been trying to learn LaTeX based on my own songbook project.
I would like chords (above lyrics) to stand out - make them bold and change color - while leaving lyrics normal style.

Sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\begin{document}
\begin{song}{title={Test song}, music={unknown}}
\begin{verse}
Lo\chord{Amaj7}rem \chord{G#mi7}ipsum dolor sit a\chord{F#mi7}, \\
c\chord{Amaj7}onsectetur \chord{G#mi7}adipiscing \chord{E7sus4}elit. \\
Mo\chord{Amaj7}rbi tell\chord{G#mi7}us augue, tempus a ex\chord{F#mi7} nec, \\
co\chord{Amaj7}mmodo \chord{G#mi7} varius \chord{Esus4}est. \chord{E}
\end{verse}
\begin{bridge}
\writechord{Amaj7} \writechord{C#m7} \writechord{Esus4}
\end{bridge}
\end{song}
\end{document}
```

outputs:
[image]

I've played around with `\renewcommand{\chord}{\textbf}` but then I get *inline* chords mixed with text as below:

[image]

I need text (chords) above lyrics inserted with `\chord{}` and `\writechord{}` to be eg. bold and blue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have edited my question to give you more insights on the issue. I hope this is clear now. Looking forward for any ideas/hints.

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer appeared, moving along learning curve, I've came up with the following solution myself.
Create new command based on `\chordname`

`\newcommand{\mychordname}[1]{\color{blue}\bfseries\sffamily\chordname{#1} \mdseries\rmfamily}`

and change default chord parsing command `chord-cs=\mychordname`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setleadsheets{%
    chord-cs=\mychordname
}
\newcommand{\mychordname}[1]{\color{blue}\bfseries\sffamily\chordname{#1} \mdseries\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{song}{title={Test song}, music={unknown}}
\begin{verse}
Lo\chord{Amaj7}rem \chord{G#mi7}ipsum dolor sit a\chord{F#mi7}, \\
c\chord{Amaj7}onsectetur \chord{G#mi7}adipiscing \chord{E7sus4}elit. \\
Mo\chord{Amaj7}rbi tell\chord{G#mi7}us augue, tempus a ex\chord{F#mi7} nec, \\
co\chord{Amaj7}mmodo \chord{G#mi7} varius \chord{Esus4}est. \chord{E}
\end{verse}
\begin{bridge}
\writechord{Amaj7} \writechord{C#m7} \writechord{Esus4}
\end{bridge}
\end{song}
\end{document}
```

This produced result below, which was exactly what I was looking for
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just set the corresponding option. It is documented in the `leadsheets` manual in the section about chords.

The code below also uses the shortcuts for `\chord` (`^`) and `\writechord` (`_`) and the `-` option for chords which ignores the width of a chord – useful when a chord is wider than the sylable it is placed on.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setleadsheets{
  chords/format = \color{blue}\bfseries\sffamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title={Test song}, music={unknown}}
  \begin{verse}
    Lo^-{Amaj7}rem ^{G#mi7}ipsum dolor sit a^{F#mi7}, \\
    c^{Amaj7}onsectetur ^{G#mi7}adipiscing ^{E7sus4}elit. \\
    Mo^-{Amaj7}rbi tell^-{G#mi7}us augue, tempus a ex^{F#mi7} nec, \\
    co^{Amaj7}mmodo ^{G#mi7} varius ^{Esus4}est. ^{E}
  \end{verse}
  \begin{bridge}
    _{Amaj7} _{C#m7} _{Esus4}
  \end{bridge}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

[image]